# How get rsync to write only to USB disk, and fail if it's not mounted?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, usb-storage

Ubuntu 9.10, connected to external WD 1.5GB USB drive, called "data_3"

I connected the USB cord and all was well for a long time.
Ran nightly cron jobs rsyncing data via the internal network.

After a powerout, after which the external USB did not start,
the rsync job COPIED the data to /media/data_3, 
on the INTERNAL drive which is much smaller and ran out of space.

The rsync script points to the supposedly mounted USB drive at /media/data_3,
but when it does not exist it writes to /media/data_3, on the internal drive.

How get rsync to write only to the USB disk, and fail if it's not mounted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check beforehand if the disk is mounted (via `mount` and `grep`), and then have the script fail if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file on the external drive and test for its presence before running rsync.

`if [ -e /media/data_3/testfile ]; then rsync /source/directory /media/data_3/destination; fi` should work as a one line in bash at least. You can add an else condition to send you a mail if the file doesn't exist (meaning the partition isn't mounted, or isn't mounted in the right place).